# How to set i18n default translation language for notification language using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, internationalization, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm implementing a hybrid app on iOS and using i18n to control the notification language, supporting English (EN) and French (FR) and storing localized message strings in the app bundle.

Provide localized content from your provider server.

Store localized message strings in your app bundle.

Currently, when I set the language in General/Language & Region, the app works in the corresponding language.

However, I want the default notification language to be based on the code received from the backend. For example, if the Language & Region is set to EN and the backend returns FR, I want the app to receive notifications in FR.

I've searched for a solution to this issue, but I haven't found any relevant documentation on setting the notification language. Can anyone help me find a solution to this problem?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/customizing_the_appearance_of_notifications

Comment: I don't understand why french backend sending english notifications.

Comment: Because my app supports both English (EN) and French (FR), and stores localized message strings in the app bundle. If a user chooses to sign in with the French language, I will set the notification language to French (FR), regardless of the user's device General/Language & Region settings, which may be set to English (EN), Canada(CA),...